# s3fs-mounted S3 bucket shows bad filesizes

Tags: centos, amazon-s3, ftp, fuse, s3fs

**Background:**
I have an Amazon S3 bucket with data uploaded using the AWS web interface. Now I need to give permissions-based access to paths within my buckets to FTP users. To do this, I'm running vsftpd and s3fs on a fresh Amazon EC2 instance. Problem is that bucket contents have the pathname instead of a dotfile and the huge filesize creates an exception in vsftpd. `ls -la` looks like this:

```
$ pwd
/mnt/my-bucket-name/pathname
$ ls -la
total 1
drwxrwxr-x 1 root root                    0 Jun 16 19:54 dir1
drwxrwxr-x 1 root root                    0 Jun 16 19:54 dir2
---------- 1 root root 18446744073709551615 Dec 31  1969 pathname
```

Whereas it should look more like:

```
$ ls -la
total 500
drwxrwxr-x 1 root root                    500 Jun 16 19:54 .
drwxrwxr-x 1 root root                    500 Jun 16 19:54 ..
drwxrwxr-x 1 root root                    500 Jun 16 19:54 dir1
drwxrwxr-x 1 root root                    500 Jun 16 19:54 dir2
```

When FTP users try to connect they get an error:

```
ftp> ls
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||14017|).
150 Here comes the directory listing.
500 OOPS: invalid inode size in vsf_sysutil_statbuf_get_size
```

The bucket is mounted with this command: `sudo s3fs my-bucket-name /mnt/my-bucket-name -o allow_other -o default_acl=public-read`

I created a ticket on the s3fs google code page a month ago, hacked at this for hours and I'm stumped. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: P.S.: If anyone can point me in the direction of another way to achieve the same objective I'd be equally grateful (though somewhat dismayed to abandon what seems like an interesting problem)...

Comment: P.P.S: If anyone out there is willing and able to solve this problem I'd be quite happy to put a monetary bounty on this... So long as you're okay with sharing your solution on this thread so the community benefits. PM me or post here if that sounds interesting.

Comment: Could you retest with a newer s3fs?  I cannot reproduce these symptoms with the latest version.  If the problem persists, please include the output of -o curldbg.